# price of publishing a lightning component to appexchange

Tags: lightning-aura-components, appexchange

What does it cost to publish a lightning component on AppExchange? I assume this isn't free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exact fees, you will need to check with salesforce ISV team. The cost of the security review is same as hosting any other app on the appexchange and it's no different .

Also the process of getting it on to the appexchange is similar to putting an app on appexchange.